# Diffrence between undefined point and the derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$ now let's say I want to evaluate the function at $x=0$, I can't it's undefined its a $\frac{0}{0}$ situation. I can compute that the $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x} = 0$ meaning that if I choose $x$ that is close to $0$, $\frac{x^2}{x}$ is going to close to $0$ and that the closer $x$ is to $0$, the closer $\frac{x^2}{x}$ is going to be to $0$, but that's not the same thing as saying that $f(0) = 0$.
Now lets suppose I want to compute the derivative of a function $g(x)$ for some $x$ value $x=c$, the derivative in this case is defined as: $\lim_{dx \to 0} \frac{g(c + dx) - g(c)}{dx} $. But as far as I understand it, the interpretation of the derivative is as instantaneous rate of change, or the slope of the function at a single point, and both interpretations sugget to just put $dx = 0$ on the limit, but that would get us to $\frac{f(x+0)-f(x)}{0} = \frac{f(x)-f(x)}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$ which is exactly the same problem we had earlier with $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$ when $x=0$. So my question is how can we have two instances of the undefined  $\frac{0}{0}$ but for one (the function value) we say that despite the fact that limit approaches some number, the instance is undefined, and for one (the derivative at a point) we that the instance does equal to the limit?

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamental mistakes you're making:

- you're forgetting that a function is not just a "formula" like $x^2/x$ or $x^3\sin(e^{-\cosh(\arctan(x))})$  or anything else. A function in mathematics has a precise definition. But for most purposes, the following definition will serve us well: to specify a function we have to specify three pieces of information, $(f,A,B)$, where $A,B$ are sets and $f$ is the "rule" which tells you how to assign each $a \in A$, an element $f(a) \in B$. We summarize all this in the notation $f:A \to B$. Here we call $A$ the **domain** of $f$, we call $B$ the **target space or codomain** of $f$.
- Next mistake is that you're applying limit theorems when they're not valid to get things like $\dfrac{0}{0}$. Always remember the following fact: **before applying ANY theorem, always check the hypotheses of the theorem first, and only apply the theorem if the hypotheses have been satisfied**.

So, the more precise way of setting up the situation is as follows. We first consider the function $f:\Bbb{R} \setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by the rule
\begin{align}
f(x) &:= \dfrac{x^2}{x}.
\end{align}
Notice how I gave you all three pieces of information:

1. I told you the domain is $A = \Bbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$,
2. I told you the target space is $B = \Bbb{R}$,
3. I told you the specific rule for $f$. In this case, for each number $x$ in the set $A$, we first square it, and then divide by it. In formulas, we simply write $f(x) = x^2/x$. Now, of course, if $x \in A$, it means $x \neq 0$, so that we can perform the division by $x$, and simplify to get $f(x) = x$ (this is of course one of the basic properties of real numbers, that the "cancellation" holds for non-zero denominators).

However, it is completely meaningless to even ask the question "what is $f(0)$?" It is complete nonsense, because $0$ is not even an element of the domain, $A$. So, it just doesn't make sense to even write down $f(0)$. Once again, just to make myself super clear: **if an element is not in the domain of the function, we cannot talk about the value of the function when plugging in that element**. You should literally ingrain this into your mind as being nonsense. It is almost as meaningless as asking "what is Spongebob plus Jupiter".

Now, while asking what is $f(0)$ is completely meaningless, what is very meaningful is to ask

> "does $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ exist? If it exists, what is this limit equal to?"

As you've seen, the limit is $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}x = 0$. Note that in general, if you want to calculate $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$, it doesn't matter whether or not $f$ is defined at $a$; all that matters is that $f$ is defined "around $a$". THis is because in the definition of limit, we don't care what the function does at the point itself, all we care about is how it behaves near the point in question.

Now what we can do is define a NEW function $F: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, by the rule
\begin{align}
F(x) &:=
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\
\lim_{t \to 0}f(t) & \text{if $x= 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
If you simplify what this means, it says:
\begin{align}
F(x) &= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{x} & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
0 & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\
0 & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases} \\
&= x
\end{align}
For this completely new function, it makes perfect sense to ask what is $F(0)$. And as I've defined it, we have $F(0) = 0$, and in fact for every real number $x$, we have $F(x) = x$. Note that I could have defined $F(0)$ to be any number I wanted; but by choosing it to be $0$, I actually ensured that my new function is continuous at the origin (i.e $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x) = F(0)$).

---

For your question regarding derivatives, no one ever said that
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} &= \dfrac{g(x + 0) - g(x)}{0} = \dfrac{0}{0}.
\end{align}
If anyone ever told you this, you should just forget about it. The very first equal sign is already false; when taking limits, you can't just "plug in $h=0$". You can only plug in limits if the function is continuous. Note that in your first equal sign, you actually made use of several theorems, none of which can be applied in this case. The first thing you did is make the incorrect step:
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} = \dfrac{\lim_{h \to 0}(g(x+h) - g(x))}{\lim_{h \to 0}h}
\end{align}
You probably did this because of the formula

> \begin{align}
> \lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \dfrac{\lim_{x \to a} P(x)}{\lim_{x \to a}Q(x)}
> \end{align}

But what you didn't do is check carefully the hypotheses of the theorem. Note that the hypotheses of theorems are just as important, if not more important than the actual "formulas". The hypothesis in this case is that:

> We have to assume $\lim_{x \to a}P(x)$ exists (when I say exists, I mean it is a real number, so by definition, it is finite), and we also have to assume $\lim_{x \to a}Q(x)$ exists, AND most importantly that $\lim_{x \to a}Q(x) \neq 0$. It is only if these three conditions are all satisfied that you can say
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \dfrac{\lim_{x \to a} P(x)}{\lim_{x \to a}Q(x)}
> \end{align}

In your case with the derivatives, in the denominator we have $h$, but $\lim_{h \to 0}h = 0$, so we cannot apply this theorem. The reason why we have the extra hypothesis of the limit being non-zero, is precisely to avoid division by $0$. ALWAYS remember this: **DIVISION BY ZERO IS YOUR WORST NIGHTMARE**. Don't ever write something like $\dfrac{\text{stuff}}{0}$. If you ever see someone writing stuff like this, it's because they're being sloppy (I myself am guilty of writing stuff like this from time to time, but I do it only because I know what I'm doing for the most part).

For an example, consider the function $g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, defined as $g(x) = \dfrac{x}{2}$ (again, notice how I gave you all 3 pieces of information for the function: domain, target space, and the actual rule). Then, for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$, and for $h \neq 0$, we have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} &= \dfrac{\dfrac{x+h}{2} - \dfrac{x}{2}}{h} = \dfrac{h}{2h} = \dfrac{1}{2},
\end{align}
where in the final equality, I am allowed to "cancel the $h$" precisely because I assumed it is non-zero from the beginning (actually, it is precisely because I assumed $h \neq 0$ that I can even write down the $\dfrac{\text{stuff}}{h}$ in the first place). Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
Once again, you can't just plug in $h=0$, and say "oh I get $\dfrac{0}{0}$", because those theorems do not even apply in this situation.